# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 50, size is 50

Tags: java, android

I am getting a string which I'm trying to convert to JSONArray. The length of the JSONArray is getting OK (if its 100 or 5000). but I am getting "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 50, size is 50". Below is my code.

```
try 
{
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(returndResultForSNID); 
    System.out.println("jsonArray: "+jsonArray.length());
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
    {
        snid = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("snid");
        //number = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("phone");                   
        phoneContactsDTOArrayList.add(new PhoneContactsDTO( contactNameArr.get(i).toString() , contactPhoneNumberArr.get(i).toString(), snid, "") );                
        //System.out.println( "Could jsonArray parse malformed JSON: " + snid +" _> "+number);
    }

} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    System.out.println( "JSONArray error: " + e.toString() );
}
```

Comment: index is starting from 0. so having collection of size 50 means that last element has 49 index

Comment: The problem is that contactNameArr or contactPhoneNumberArr is not the same size as your jsonArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are 0 based.

It means that an array of size 50 has index from 0 to 49.

`contactNameArr` and `contactPhoneNumberArr` are probably smaller than the size of `jsonArray`. In particular `jsonArray` has a size bigger than 51 and one of the others has a dimension of 50.

Comment: Where is this problem exactly in the code of the op? I can't seem to find any place for it.

Comment: Answer is indeed unrelated. The user did not check if the index exists in the other arrays it is using.

Comment: contactNameArr and contactPhoneNumberArr are probably smaller than the size of jsonArray

Comment: thank you for your suggestion @Davide Lorenzo Marino